# Redirect after a specific time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just wondering how I could make a person stay on a website for a specific time and then redirect them to a new website using JavaScript!
Thanks for your help!

I repeat, using JavaScript, this is not the same as the other ones, I want to use JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will take you to Google after 3 seconds.

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; }, 3000);
```

Please always set the timeout to variable for the possibility to clear the timeout.

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
```

`myFunction` should use `window.location.href` = `'my_Link'`;